# Check if pthread thread is blocking

Tags: pthreads, blocking

Here's the situation, I have a thread running that is partially controlled by code that I don't own. I started the thread so I have it's thread id but then I passed it off to some other code. I need to be able to tell if that other code has currently caused the thread to block from another thread that I am in control of. Is there are way to do this in pthreads? I think I'm looking for something equivalent to the getState() method in Java's Thread class (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState() ).

--------------Edit-----------------

It's ok if the solution is platform dependent. I've already found a solution for linux using the /proc file system.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There may be other/better ways than trying to mimic java.

Comment: This is for a testing framework. We're trying to control the schedule of threads so that people can test reentrant code under explicitly defined thread schedules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write wrappers for some of the pthreads functions, which would simply update some state information before/after calling the original functions.  That would allow you to keep track of which threads are running, when they're acquiring or holding mutexes (and which ones), when they're waiting on which condition variables, and so on.

Of course, this only tells you when they're blocked on pthreads synchronization objects -- it won't tell you when they're blocking on something else.

Comment: This is really good and I probably will be doing something like this. Do you think there is a way to figure out if they're blocking on something else like I/O?

Comment: I think the way to do that might depend on what they're blocking on.  If you can tell they're inactive, and not blocked on pthreads, it'd be safe to say they're waiting for something else.. but finding out _what_ might be complicated.  I haven't looked into it enough to say much for sure, though.

Answer (score -1):

Before you hand the thread off to some other code, set a flag protected by a mutex. When the thread returns from the code you don't control, clear the flag protected by the mutex. You can then check, from wherever you need to, whether the thread is in the code you don't control.

From outside the code, there is no distinction between blocked and not-blocked. If you literally checked the state of the thread, you would get nonsensical results.

For example, consider two library implementations.

A: We do all the work in the calling thread.

B: We dispatch a worker thread to do the work. The calling thread blocks until the worker is done.

In both cases A and B the code you don't control is equally making forward progress. Your 'getstate' idea would provide different results. So it's not what you want.

Comment: That doesn't work because the threads state (block or unblocked) may change before I ever get control of it again.

Comment: Of course, but why would you care? If you're going to check if an operation is still going on after a minute (maybe to decide to cancel it or move on), you don't care if it happens to finish the split-second after you check. Once you decide enough time has passed and you determine it is still going on, you have to irrevocably decide to give up. You'd have the same situation with the 'getstate' you asked about.

Comment: For why I'd care, please look at the comment I made for the original question.

Comment: I think my explanation shows why you shouldn't care. The result you got is invalid the second you get it no matter what.